# Цикл и массив

Tags: javascript

Подскажите разницу на примере, изначально - `undefined`. Если меняю как в комментарии, то все нормально!

```
var days = ['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun'];

for(var i = 0; days.length > i ; days.length--) {
document.write(days[days.length] + '<br>');  
    //**Если так - document.write(days[days.length-1] + '<br>') то     все выводится нормально.**

}

document.write(days.length); //  общее число единиц массива уменьшается
```

Comment: элемент days[days.length] обычно в массивах не существует:)

Comment: days[days.length]-это индекс доступа к элементам массива .

Comment: ага, можно использовать вместо `.push()`

>Подскажите разницу на примере

элементов в массиве 7, но т.к. индексация идёт с нуля, то последний элемент 6-ой, в чём проблема не пойму?

    for(var i = days.length; i--; ) { // начинаем с последнего элемента и уменьшаем счётчик
         document.write(days[i] + '<br>'); 
    }

Comment: Спасибо за примеры,но я хочу разобраться логически почему при уменьшении days.length-- в document.write(days[days.length]) все 7 значений undefined!? хотя days.length уменьшается с 7 до 0.Почему при уменьшении,начиная с индекса № 6 он не выводит значения массива?

Comment: т.к. 

    for(var i = 0; days.length > i ; days.length--) {
        document.write(days[days.length] + '<br>');
    }

эквивалентно

    for(var i = 0; days.length > i ; ) {
        document.write(days[days.length] + '<br>');
        days.length--;
    }

а если вы выполняете `days.length--`, это автоматически уменьшает кол-во элементо массива на единицу

пруф:

    var days = ['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun'];
    days.length--;
    console.log(days); // ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"]

Comment: По моему примеру,при 1-ой итерации должно быть 7,так как 7-го элемента в массиве нет будет: undefined, потом же days.length-- и уже проверка условия начинается с 6-ти,6-ой элемент уже есть 'Sun',но получается опять undefined!? Вот это и не понимаю.

Comment: вы мой комментарий читали? вы видите, что после `days.length--;` элемента `'Sun'` в массиве нету?

Comment: Невнимательность подвела.Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Ужас какой.

```
var days = ['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun'];

for(var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) { 
  document.write(days[i] + '<br>');
}

document.write(days.length);
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду не сначала выводить,а с конца.

Comment: var days = ['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun'];
    for(var i = days.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
      document.write(days[i] + '<br>');
    }
    
    document.write(days.length);

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScript есть специальный метод для инвертирования массива - [reverse()](http://javascript.ru/Array/reverse).

Если уж так интересно играться с сортировкой, то попробуйте метод - [sort()](http://javascript.ru/Array/sort).